# Live Stream application in Lumia 535

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-535, streaming

I have tried the application named **Ivms 4500**. Its working fine on my friends Android, which detects the active cameras and can be played at the same time. My windows don't connect at all If I put the Ip/Domain, Address etc.

Is there any active user who can help me out? I need to use it!

Or any other working app. anyone knows!